# How can I emulate Orderless attribute?

Tags: function-construction, expression-manipulation

Suppose I want an expression to automatically sort its arguments. This can be done via

```
SetAttributes[f, Orderless]
f[3, 2, 1]
(*output is f[1, 2, 3]*)
```

Just as an exercise, I want to emulate this behavior myself with

```
f[x__] := f[Sequence @@ Sort[{x}]]
```

which doesn't work due to infinite iteration.

I would be enlightened if anyone can show me an example how to implement this.

Comment: `f[x__] /; ! OrderedQ[{x}] := f[Sequence @@ Sort[{x}]]`?

Comment: Nice! I am completely unaware conditional patterns can be written this way.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A couple of ways:

```
f[x__] /; ! OrderedQ[{x}] := f @@ Sort[{x}]

call : f[x__] := Block[{f}, Sort[call] /; ! OrderedQ[call]]
```

The first way seems better, or at least faster.

Comment: Can you comment on the second approach? I don't understand how Block avoided infinite recursion.

Comment: @ChongWang `Block` temporarily removes any definitions of `f`. When say you execute `f[3, 2, 1]`, (1) it becomes `Sort[f[3, 2, 1]]` with `f` having no definition, (2) which becomes `f[1, 2, 3]`, (3) which exits `Block`, at which point `f` regains its definition, and (4) `f[1, 2, 3]` is reevaluated but is now ordered and fails the condition for the definition to be applied.  You can observe more fully what happens in `Trace[f[3, 2, 1]]`. You can also compare the two and see why there is difference in speed. (I don't have an explanation for why it seems to do step (4) twice.)

Comment: @ChongWang I sometimes use `Block` to hold up the execution of the function while the arguments are being constructed.  Another way is to use `Hold` and `ReleaseHold`: For instance, `f[x__] /; ! OrderedQ[List[x]] := ReleaseHold@Sort[Hold[f][x]]`.

Comment: Thank you. I have tried `Trace` but still don't understand the strategy. I would have anticipated (1) If the pattern match fails, the `Block` should return nothing; (2) A failed match within block will not prevent `f[1,2,3]` to be evaluated again.

Comment: @ChongWang When all definitions fail to match a call, the call is returned.  So in `f[1, 2, 3]` the pattern match fails because the arguments are ordered, evaluation stops, and `f[1, 2, 3]` is returned.  Keep in mind that definitions like `Block[{,,}, code; returnValue /; condition]` are treated in a special way. The block will start to be evaluated, including any `code` that precedes the `Condition`, which has to be the last statement.  That all gets thrown away if `condition` evaluates to `False`.  Here is the `Trace` with comments added, fwiw: http://i.stack.imgur.com/TU2kZ.png